# How to create a dataframe from extracted hashtags?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, twitter, hashtag

I have used below code to extract hashtags from tweets.

```
def find_tags(row_string):
    tags = [x for x in row_string if x.startswith('#')]
    
    return tags

df['split'] = df['text'].str.split(' ')

df['hashtags'] = df['split'].apply(lambda row : find_tags(row))
df['hashtags'] = df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x : str(x).replace('\\n', ',').replace('\\', '').replace("'", ""))
df.drop('split', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

However, when I am counting them using the below code I am getting output that is counting each character.

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(df.hashtags.sum())
data = pd.DataFrame([d]).T
data
```

Output I am getting is:

[image: Output]

I think the problem lies with the code that I am using to extract hashtags. But I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do not post links to external websites. Post your sample dataset as copy-paste-able formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `find_tags` by `replace` in list comprehension with `split` and for count values use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
def find_tags(row_string):
    return [x.replace('\\n', ',').replace('\\', '').replace("'", "") 
            for x in row_string.split() if x.startswith('#')]

df['hashtags'] = df['text'].apply(find_tags)
```

and then:

```
data = df.hashtags.explode().value_counts().rename_axis('val').reset_index(name='count')
```